# Twitter v1 stream API returns wrong mentions

Tags: twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I'm tracking all mentions of @UN with Tweepy using Twitter stream v1 API. However, I'm also getting all mentions of usernames *containing* @UN such as @UN_Women. I could filter them out in a post-processing step but this seems very inefficient.

Is there any way to avoid this?

This is my code:

```
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text)

myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()

myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=myStreamListener())

myStream.filter(track=['@UN'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if tweepy provides any further functionalities to avoid this. But what you can do here is, filter out the results while saving it to your database or csv.
Check the json response and look for `entities` object and in that check for `user_mentions` and `screen_name`. Save only the one with your desired `screen_name`

Answer (score 0):

Using `follow` instead of `track` should work. With `follow`, you supply a list of user IDs:

```
myStream.filter(follow=['14159148'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but I don't think the follow parameter returns mentions... 

From https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/basic-stream-parameters 

The stream will not contain:

Tweets mentioning the user (e.g. “Hello @twitterapi!”).